# Вернуть исходные значения массива на PHP

Tags: массивы, php, unset

Есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aeef6577aece329qdaece329ee1aefc7539aaeceaecb1698fe04cfe01a4f3c60937d1df
    [1] => 2b3257ce2b16cfe92b1s6cfe9592b24884e22b162b13ebef7bdc33f462e1241659b9c581
    [2] => 5320142d530d1c0b530sdasd1c0bs98533f5bac5530d53080d03c7e6d4c4207753778d55
    [3] => 2dd804662df8aac12df8aac1362ded6622df82dfd8ec77d32514f9a65b8298883793c
)
```

Есть функция, которая удаляет определённую строку в массиве:

```
function _array_del($a) {
 global $tokens;
 // ищем ключ массива по его значению
 foreach($tokens as $key => $value) {
  if($value == $a) unset($tokens[$key]); // удаляем элемент массива
 }
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($tokens);
}
```

Есть вызовы функций:

```
// удаляем первый элемент в массиве
_array_del('2b3257ce2b16cfe92b1s6cfe9592b24884e22b162b13ebef7bdc33f462e1241659b9c581');
// удаляем третий элемент в массиве
_array_del('2dd804662df8aac12df8aac1362ded6622df82dfd8ec77d32514f9a65b8298883793c');
```

Проблема такая. Когда вызываешь 1 раз функцию, всё идет правильно, удаляется ОДИН элемент массива и из 4-х значений, остается 3. А вот когда ставишь и вторую функцию, то также удаляется нужный элемент массива, но удаляет, исходя из того, что осталось при удалении в первый раз.

**При первом разе:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => aeef6577aece329qdaece329ee1aefc7539aaeceaecb1698fe04cfe01a4f3c60937d1df
    [2] => 5320142d530d1c0b530sdasd1c0bs98533f5bac5530d53080d03c7e6d4c4207753778d55
    [3] => 2dd804662df8aac12df8aac1362ded6622df82dfd8ec77d32514f9a65b8298883793c
)
```

**При втором разе:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => aeef6577aece329qdaece329ee1aefc7539aaeceaecb1698fe04cfe01a4f3c60937d1df
    [2] => 5320142d530d1c0b530sdasd1c0bs98533f5bac5530d53080d03c7e6d4c4207753778d55
)
```

Т.е, когда мы удалили в первый раз, осталось 3 значения из 4-х (правильно), а во второй раз - 2 значения из 4-х (неправильно).

Нужно каким-то образом сделать, чтобы при каждом вызове функции, брался исходный массив (без всяких удалений) и удалял по 1 элементу, чтобы всегда оставалось 3 элемента в массиве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Избавьтесь от глобальной переменной если это возможно.
Пускай функция _array_del принимает на вход массив и строку которую нужно удалить. Тогда функция будет работать с копией массива.

Как-то так:

```
//code
$token_array // будет массив с токенами
$new_arr = _array_del($token_array, "строка_для_удаления")
//$new_arr теперь содержит обрезанный массив при этом $token_array не как не изменился.
```

Только функцию нужно переделать примерно так:

```
function _array_del($tokens, $str_to_del) {

 // ищем ключ массива по его значению
 foreach($tokens as $key => $value) {
  if($value == $str_to_del) unset($tokens[$key]); // удаляем элемент массива
 }
 return $tokens;
}
```

А вывод(echo) и print_r используйте там откуда вы вызываете _array_del();

Comment: @KryDos, супер! Избавился от глобальной переменной и всё встало на свои места! Спасибо!

Comment: используйте array_search [http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php] вместо foreach, чтобы  не перебирать все элементы